# Run Google Sheets script on insert

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

So, i have a google form, and based on the data of the submitted form, a response is generated, i want that response to be emailed to the person who completed the form
Is there a way to send an email when a new row is inserted in the answer sheets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I've accomplished this in the past is to write a simple google docs script to listen to the onChange trigger of a spreadsheet and send an email with the contents of the row of said sheet. Here are the specific steps:

1. With your google sheet open go to Tools > Script editor...

[image: open script editor in google sheets]

2. This will bring you to the script associated to this file where you can write a simple function to send the contents of the last rows of your sheet. Something like the following would work:

```js
function sendEmailOfLastEditedRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  var cols = sheet.getLastColumn();


  // Fetch the range of cells A2:D5
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, numRows, cols)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Fetch your row as an array
  var lastRowData = data[0];

  // Format data by separating values into comma separated list for email
  var emailContent = lastRowData.join(",");

  // Send an email (change this to your email)
  MailApp.sendEmail('alex@simoes.com', 'Email subject', emailContent);

  // Log contents for debugging      
  Logger.log(emailContent);
}
```

3. Add a trigger in the script editor to run this function when the google sheet is edited: Edit > Current project's triggers

[image: add google sheet trigger]